# eclipse files created outside of its workspace, Why?

Tags: eclipse

While opening eclipse I chose a workspace in `D:\education\myWorkspace` but after closing eclipse I find its

- metadata
- configuration
- RemoteSystemsTempFiles
- someMoreFiles

aree all created in D:\, but not in my workspace - why?

Answer (score 0):

Simply spoken, because eclipse stores information in different places.

Some go into your workspaces, some go other places. 
See [here](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fmulti_user_installs.html) for starters. As you can see, eclipse differentiates between install, configuration and instance areas.

If you want to, you can give command line arguments to the **eclipse** binary in order to change the default settings; for example to force eclipse to use the same configuration space, even when going for different workspaces.

Comment: thank you for the link you have given me I understand some point not all as I m a beginner. But when last time I created one workspace but not choose from existed one then my eclipse created its files inside that workspace, can you tell me how to make eclipse create its files inside my workspace?